# Unitary Plan Wind Tunnel

Tags: traduction, anglais, terminologie

Je dois traduire cette légende issue du site de la NASA :

"The Unitary Plan Wind Tunnel (UPWT) complex at NASA Ames Research Center includes the 11-by 11-Foot Transonic and the 9-by 7-foot Supersonic Wind Tunnels."

Hormis conserver la dénomination de la V.O., je ne vois pas comment traduire Unitary Plan Wind Tunnel. Ou en périphrasant : Soufflerie réalisée dans le cadre du Plan unitaire.

Answer (score 2):

Il me semble en effet qu'il soit difficile de faire court. De plus il y a le mot "complex" qui s'y rapporte ensuite. Personnellement, je traduirais par

> Le complexe de souffleries du "Plan Unitaire" (UPWT)...

mais cela dépend aussi de la familiarité des lecteurs avec l'acronyme UPWT(personne ne va "traduire" NASA par exemple).

A noter que "tunnel aérodynamique" est parfois utilisé, mais ça allonge encore la phrase.

Comment: En effet, je vais tricoter en ce sens.